# Do triggers exist for folders in S3 bucket when all objects are deleted?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have a S3 folder structure as below:

s3://ABC/sample-file.csv

I want to trigger a lambda function whenever sample-file lands in ABC folder. Now, the requirement is to move(copy and delete) the sample file. Now, when I delete the sample-file using python boto3, even ABC folder is deleted as it has no objects.

```
boto3_session = boto3.client('s3')
boto3_session.delete_object(Bucket = Bucketname, Key = 'ABC/sample-file.csv')
```

I want to trigger that lambda function whenever I write sample file to ABC folder again. My question is will the previously defined lambda function be triggered as the ABC folder will be created again?

Alternatively, can I retain ABC folder without any files?

Comment: In S3 there are no folders! What you think of and what frequently are called "folders" are merely keys associated with the object, frequently used to speed up access (e.g. using ABC/file and XYZ/file can speed up object access significantly).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Remember that there aren't actually folders in S3, but rather the folder path is just part of the key name.  The folders are just a friendly way to display the information in the console and on the cli.

Once you create the S3 event notification it will stay in effect even if you deleted the last file in a "folder" and it appears there is no folder.